# Remove element from a listView (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

My goal with this code is to present a list (´listView´) that is primarily populated with values provided by the developer and then moves to a second part where items that the user clicks are deleted.

The first part goes as desired, the list appears as defined. But in the second part the program does not run, closing the application.

File MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val defns = ArrayList<String>()
    private lateinit var myAdapter : ArrayAdapter<String>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        putElementsList()

        listView_elements.setOnItemClickListener{ _, _, index, _ ->
            defns.removeAt(index)
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        } 
    }

    private fun putElementsList() {
        defns.add("piggy")
        defns.add("dumas")
        defns.add("kika")
        defns.add("songahn")
        defns.add("festeira")

        defns.shuffle() 

        val myAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, defns)
        listView_elements.adapter = myAdapter
    }
}
```

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="word"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/TextView_word" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_title" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Vocab builder game"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:id="@+id/textView_title"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.043"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="30sp" android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="395dp"
            android:layout_height="600dp"
            android:id="@+id/listView_elements"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TextView_word"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem here is when you create an "Adapter" you are assigning to a local `val myAdapter` so when you are trying to notifydatachange, class member is still found uninitialized.

Solution

change :

`val myAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, defns)`

to

`myAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, defns)`